# What does the .current property of the querySelector method refer to?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I came across this line of code via a snippet on https://usehooks.com,

`document.querySelector('body').current`

I haven't been able to find `.current` in the specification at all.
I was hoping someone could clarify its purpose in this context.

It's being used within the `IntersectionObserver` API in the full example (below) - perhaps the API is exposing the property?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

---

Following is the full source code:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

// Usage
function App() {
  // Ref for the element that we want to detect whether on screen
  const ref = useRef();
  // Call the hook passing in ref and root margin
  // In this case it would only be considered onScreen if more ...
  // ... than 300px of element is visible.
  const onScreen = useOnScreen(ref, '-300px');

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ height: '100vh' }}>
        <h1>Scroll down to next section </h1>
      </div>
      <div
        ref={ref}
        style={{
          height: '100vh',
          backgroundColor: onScreen ? '#23cebd' : '#efefef'
        }}
      >
        {onScreen ? (
          <div>
            <h1>Hey I'm on the screen</h1>
            <img src="https://i.giphy.com/media/ASd0Ukj0y3qMM/giphy.gif" />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <h1>Scroll down 300px from the top of this section </h1>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

// Hook
function useOnScreen(ref, margin = '0px') {
  // State and setter for storing whether element is visible
  const [isIntersecting, setIntersecting] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      ([entry]) => {
        // Update our state when observer callback fires
        setIntersecting(entry.isIntersecting);
      },
      {
        rootMargin: margin,
        root: document.querySelector('body').current
      }
    );
    if (ref.current) {
      observer.observe(ref.current);
    }
    return () => {
      observer.unobserve(ref.current);
    };
  }, []); // Empty array ensures that effect is only run on mount and unmount

  return isIntersecting;
}
```

Comment: `.current` would be a property on the resulting element (i.e. **nothing** to do with querySelector) ... which in this case is the `body` element ... but, that doesn't mean anything either

Comment: as an aside ... isn't `document.querySelector('body')` ... just a long winded way of writing `document.body`?

Comment: @Bravo not always... You may be in a non HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector('body').current` is just a property of the `body` element, which has nothing to do with `document.querySelector`. It may have been set somewhere else as it is not an existing property of the `body` element.

```js
var body = document.querySelector("body");
console.log("body.current:", "body.current");
body.current = "SOMEVALUE";
console.log("After setting body.current");
console.log("body.current:", "body.current");
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to disappoint, but it doesn't do anything. It's just a way to supply `undefined` to the `IntersectionObserver` API. If you replace `document.querySelector('body').current` with `undefined` or remove the entire `root` field altogether, you still get the same result.

I removed that field to test it to verify the same behavior. Try it yourself in the Codesandbox link [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/j2z87w0px5).

As seen by [this comment](https://gist.github.com/gragland/d1175eb983772b077cb17ae0841c5329#gistcomment-2754991) on the example, it can be removed entirely:

> You can remove root entirely, since it defaults to the viewport anyway (also document.querySelector('body').current is always undefined, could be document.body but isn't needed anyway)